# Visual Studio Code gets unresponsive with no extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code on an Ubuntu machine (22.4) but when I run it I get a blank window with just the menu bar, and after a few seconds I get a dialog box:

> The window is not responding

I can navigate the menu, but there is no action performed (not even "Exit (Ctrl-Q)"). I have to close the window either by the [Close] button in the dialog or the window's close [X] button.

```
code --list-extensions
```

Show no extensions

```
code --verbose
```

Would report a

```
[main 2023-05-18T02:35:23.483Z] CodeWindow: detected unresponsive
```

line whenever the dialog appears. Also, menu actions are reflected with messages such as

```
[main 2023-05-18T02:46:05.572Z] menubar#runActionInRenderer { type: 'commandId', commandId: 'workbench.action.quit' }
```

however no action is performed.

I have also find errors such as

```
[15367:0517/213509.698923:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable()
```

Which seems related with the graphic card. When running

```
code --disable-gpu --verbose
```

This error does not appear but the behavior is not improved: the application is still unresponsive.

I have reinstalled VS Code after deleting all user folders and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found no solution other than uninstalling through apt and installing through snap, that seems to work for now.